# How to get data into textfields for editing?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I have this code (XCode 4, using Storyboards with ARC) which takes data from an array (rArray) and places it in the textfields from which it originally came from (I want to edit the data).  The array (rArray) has valid data in it, but nothing is in the textfields.  What am I doing wrong?

```
SingletonListOfReadings *rShareInstance = [SingletonListOfReadings sharedInstance];
rArray *ra = [rShareInstance.listOfReadings objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];  //  get an rArray object out of listOfReadings

//  place data back into textfields
EnterDataViewController *edvc = [[EnterDataViewController alloc] init];
edvc.txtSTA1.text = ra.rSTA;
edvc.txtBS.text = ra.rBS;
edvc.txtFS.text = ra.rFS;
edvc.txtDesc.text = ra.rDesc;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:edvc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it... I took the original code and moved it to the View controller (edvc) which handles the objects.  Then I called it from the view controller where I needed the data.

Works fine... I think the problem was in the addressing of the receiving textfields.

Thank you for your help... I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

the UI text elements in VC are not yet set when you try to populate it (it will be set only after [self.navigationController pushViewController:edvc animated:YES]; (and only when it gets viewDidLoad).

easy way to go is to change txtSTA1, txtBS, txtFS etc to strings (make sure they are in edvc .h file), pupulate them as u do now

so, txtSTA1STR is a string in the .H file of edvc
and txtSTA is a UI text element in the xib (or programmatically) in edvc

```
EnterDataViewController *edvc = [[EnterDataViewController alloc] init];
edvc.txtSTA1STR = ra.rSTA;
edvc.txtBSSTR= ra.rBS;
edvc.txtFSSTR= ra.rFS;
edvc.txtDescSTR= ra.rDesc;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:edvc animated:YES];
```

and inside edvc

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   txtSTA1.text = txtSTA1STR;
   //... etc
}
```

Comment: I have them set up as properties, and the values of ra.rxx are still not getting to the strTxt... fields.  I'm using XCode4 with Storyboards and ARC.

Comment: make sure they are defined as Strings in the .H, with property , and synthesize them in the M. then in -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
do : textUIElement.text = the stringName;